# acquire::http::proxy for only specified repositories

Tags: networking, apt, proxy, repository

Is there a way to use acquire::http::proxy for some repositories?

I'm in a network that has a proxy server. So everybody has to update /etc/apt/apt.conf adding the lines like

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::socks::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Everything working ok with that.

But now we have a LOT of ubuntu machines and I want to do a local ubuntu mirror.

So we should erase those proxy lines.... except for external repositories.

So, how do I configure something like that?

In RH based distros you can have a global proxy setting for yum and then use individual proxy settings for each repository. But didn't found something similar un Ubuntu.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I got it working as I wanted.

For every local mirror you have to add a line like this:

```
Acquire::http::proxy::local.mirror.address "DIRECT";
```

So, in /etc/apt/apt.conf I got something like:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::http::proxy::local.mirror.address "DIRECT";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::socks::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

That way I can use our web proxy for outside/external repositories and be able to use our local repository mirror without a web proxy.

Comment: This works perfectly, but where is the documentation for this??

Comment: @chronospoon, I think the apt authors think you are a master at Python and will know exactly how this part works. 8-)

Comment: The other way around may be like this: `Acquire::http::proxy::HOST_NAME_TO_BE_PROXIED "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";` e.g.: `Acquire::http::proxy::download.docker.com "http://1.2.3.4:1234";`

Comment: Does apt not accept wildcards here..?

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solve this problem.

Remove all the acquire lines in apt.conf and bring it back to it's pristine state

Now, export your http_proxy as

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port 
export no_proxy=.xyz.org
```

where xyz.org is your local domain name

Now finally run apt-get as follows.

```
sudo -E apt-get update
```

The -E option make the http_proxy variable available to apt-get. That's it. Proxy is now used for all external connections and not for the internal network.

Comment: This method is not compatible with the rest of the system.